# Unity: Spawn element on accurate position over time

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wish to spawn enemies which are moving on the same speed at a specific position repeating every x milliseconds.

The problem with update() function in Unity is that it occurs in a non deterministic time, so I cannot spawn in the accurate position, and I get delays and inaccurate positions of the elements.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use e.g coroutines [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). With `WaitForSeconds()` class to achieve time delay.

Comment: Or use `InvokeRepeating`.

Comment: If it's really a must to be frame precise on this, you can use FixedUpdate() instead

Comment: How Accurate is the InvokeRepeating? I assume that it is bound by the specific frame time, isn't it? In this case there will always be an offset..

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines are really useful to trigger methods periodically.

You can check [this Unity forum post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/750932/spawn-an-object-using-yieldstartcoroutine.html) to see how it works.

```
IEnumerator SpawnDelay()
{
    Spawn(); //your spawn method
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    StartCoroutine("SpawnDelay"); //Restarting the coroutine after the 5 sec delay
}
```

Comment: What if I need, for example spawn EXACTLY every 0.5 seconds - will Coroutine be able to handle it? or again, in this case there might be an offset?

Comment: Coroutines should be able to spawn an item every 0.5 seconds, as it's restarting itself after the specified delay in the code I used above. But about the position, if the spawn position isn't changing, they should all spawn in the same position. But, are collisions handled with those ? If the previously spawned item is still in the way, that might be the cause of the offset. If not, I'm not really sure why position is incorrect.